# What are the basics for switching from DirectX to SlimDX?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, managed-directx

I have an old application for playing video that uses DirectX and I would like to update it and prevent the "error" of Loader lock among other things.

Can I ask what are the basic steps for converting the application? What do I have to pay special attention to?

Currently I have references in the project that point to local DLL files that I have added to a local folder. This is not a good approach and another reason for this question.

```
Microsoft.DirectX
Microsoft.DirectX.DirectInput
```

Comment: I know this isn't part of your question, but you ought to check out SharpDX... it has high level wrappers too.

Comment: Hi @PsychoDad I have been wondering on SharpDX and I am uncertain if I should move to it or start by migrating to SlimDx and then change to SharpDX. Is it a more or less direct migration from DirectX to SharpDX?

Comment: SharpDX is a direct mapping to DirectX API so it should be an easy migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to change the namespaces to the `SlimDx` namespaces.  At that point, you'll have to migrate some code, as some of the names are different in `SlimDx` vs. Managed DirectX.

That being said, the basic API calls for DirectX 9 are very similar, so the migration is not too bad once you get going.

Comment: Hi @Reed Copsey Thanks for the reply. I am going to use SharpDX and minimize the migration steps. If it fails, I will revert and migrate to SlimDX.

Comment: Although I am going to use SharpDX I have made a basic test on migration and this would be the most straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to this thread, but I have used SlimDX for a year and I'm nearly but not quite finished translating my embryonic game to SharpDX (because I want to use XAML and a couple other reasons). I highly recommend both, and putting aside SharpDX's advantages (DX11.1, WinRT, XAML, some speed improvements), I would say that SlimDX is as close to managed DX as your going to get, it's equal to SharpDX, without considering those advantages that I mentioned.

I hope the point I'm making is that SlimDX is a closely mapped framework, equal to SharpDX. In that regard, SharpDX can't be recommended alone, without mention of SlimDX. And also I want to make the point that SharpDX will not minimize the migration steps over SlimDX, if that's what you're thinking. They are very similar, more similar than you think if you are of the opinion that you might fail in one and succeed in the other. If you can work it out in one, then you can work it out in the other, they are that much alike. So much alike that I wished they would rejoin as a team and work together on a unified package of frameworks. There is just too much overlap for them to be distinct projects IMO.

Comment: Hi @Gavin Williams, thanks you for the answer and just to make a context the application reads video streams and renders to individual panels, similar to CCTV and it needs an update. I will keep your information in mind since I am planning a major migration to WPF and a better usage of GPU render. At this point it only uses 8% of GPU and 70% of CPU... so something is not working.